# Laravel - join closure does not work with table reference

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

I am stuck at a mysql join query.

I currently have the following:

```
    $query = DB::table('packages')
        ->join('assigned_packages', function($join) use($id)
        {
            $join->on('packages.id', '=', 'assigned_packages.registered_package_id')
                ->where('assigned_packages.customer_id', '=', $id);
        })
        ->join('registered_packages', function($join)
        {
            $join->on('packages.id', '=', 'registered_packages.id')
                ->where('registered_packages.id', '=', 1);
        });
```

This works fine, but as you can see i have a hardcoded **1**:

```
->where('registered_packages.id', '=', 1);
```

This **1** should be replaced with the value from the table **assigned_packages** and the column **registered_package_id**. I tried

```
    $query = DB::table('packages')
        ->join('assigned_packages', function($join) use($id)
        {
            $join->on('packages.id', '=', 'assigned_packages.registered_package_id')
                ->where('assigned_packages.customer_id', '=', $id);
        })
        ->join('registered_packages', function($join)
        {
            $join->on('packages.id', '=', 'registered_packages.id')
                ->where('registered_packages.id', '=', 'assigned_packages.registered_package_id');
        });
```

But that does not work. What am I doing wrong? I guess i need the result from the first join for the second one. But how can I do that?

```
dd(DB::getQueryLog());
```

outputs:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["query"]=>
    string(48) "select * from `customers` where `id` = ? limit 1"
    ["bindings"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(2) "45"
    }
    ["time"]=>
    float(0.65)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["query"]=>
    string(278) "select * from `packages` inner join `assigned_packages` on `packages`.`id` = `assigned_packages`.`registered_package_id` and `assigned_packages`.`customer_id` = ? inner join `registered_packages` on `packages`.`id` = `registered_packages`.`id` and `registered_packages`.`id` = ?"
    ["bindings"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(2) "45"
      [1]=>
      string(39) "assigned_packages.registered_package_id"
    }
    ["time"]=>
    float(0.9)
  }
}
```

Comment: When you say the second one "does not work", what specific error do you get?  Also, do a `dd(\DB::getQueryLog())` after running this query and paste the results, please.

Comment: It simply does not return anything. I have updated the question with the logs. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your join closure requires either `DB::raw` like suggested, or the method that is intended for it `on`:

```
->join('registered_packages', function($join)
{
    $join->on('packages.id', '=', 'registered_packages.id')
       ->on('registered_packages.id', '=', 'assigned_packages.registered_package_id');
});
```

`where` on joins is used only for values passed to the query.

Comment: Yep, and this is the preferred method!

Answer (score 0):

In a `where`, Laravel treats the last argument as a literal string, not a table reference. So the final query is trying to match the `registered_packages.id` column against the literal string *"assigned_packages.registered_package_id"*.

To use `where` with a table reference, you need to instruct Laravel to "do as you mean", using [`DB::raw`](http://laravel.com/docs/queries#raw-expressions):

```
$join->
    on('packages.id', '=', 'registered_packages.id')->
    where('registered_packages.id', '=', \DB::raw('assigned_packages.registered_package_id'))
;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I prefer the above solution :)